# SQL Server inner join vs MS Access inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have to convert an Access query to Sql Server query.

In my FROM clause I have something like this:

```
FROM 
  (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.afield = table2.afield)
```

I'm think that my FROM clause in Sql Server should remain unchanged but I'm not sure about that.

Can you please give me confirm about that?

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis, but you don't have to. It should work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what you have, I'd take out the parenthesis though;

```
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.afield = table2.afield
```

It would also be a good idea to get into the habit of using table aliases too, something like this;

```
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.afield = t2.afield
```

As this will help the readability of the code.